# running activity from fragment, from another activity, with Onclick android

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, fragment

I am ran into a problem, I need to **run** (not open aka intent) an activity "cal.class" (with cal.xml) from the "Main Activity" with (main_ac.xml)

I have created a "calFragment.class" (linking to cal.xml )and implemented the fragment inside (main_ac.xml)

The fragment is working and the "cal.class" works perfectly (when running by itself aka separate intent)

I am trying to run the activity "cal.class" (in the background) in order to output information to the main_ac.xml or to cal.xml, as I have a fragment for cal.xml, it should output to the main_ac.xml

So I also tried creating a background service, which is being called but is not running the activity in the background
**My first version :**

Creating a On Click method inside the **"cal.class"** which has

```
"setContentView(R.layout.cal);"
```

and then tried with :

```
" setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"
```

however the mouse click was not being recognized.

**My second version :**

Creating a "On Click" inside the Main Activity which did get recognized, then I created a var for it :

```
cal calander = new cal();
calander.getresultsofAPI();
```

however this then led to a null pointer exception.

Now when running the "cal.class" inside it's own intent workings perfectly,

I just need it to run (in the background) when there is a "On Click" and output the values inside the "main_act.xml" or "cal.xml"

I have also tried creating background services to run the activity in the background but I had no luck with that either. The service gets calls and runs, but it does not run the "cal.class"

I have been scratching my head around this for days and been searching all over the web for a solution.

**Any feedback is much appreciated**

Thank you :)

This is a *simplified* version :

Cal Fragment Class :

```
public class FragmentCalander extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calander, container, false);

    System.out.println("clanader Fragment loaded");

    return view;
}

}
```

Cal Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //code running, example :
// protected void getResultsFromApi() {}, etc..
}
```

Main Activity :

```
findViewById(R.id.fragmentcalander).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, service.class);
    startService(intent);


    ImageButton refreashicon = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.refreashevents) ;
    refreashicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            final cal calander = new cal();
            calander.getResultsFromApi();

// or 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, service.class);
    startService(intent);
// however this service intent can not work inside the onClick, only outside it

        }
    });
```

Service Activity:

```
public class service extends Service {

cal calander = new cal();

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    service getService() {
        return service.this;
    }
}


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    System.out.println("new service started");
    calander.getResultsFromApi();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return mBinder;
}
}
```

Main Activity.xml :

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="geepool.smart_wardobe.FragmentCalander"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentcalander"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/start" />
```

If you have any ideas, i would **love** to hear them, this is now frying my brain

Comment: Is `cal.class` extending any `Activity` class? Can you post whole class? so it is easier to analyze the problem.